# ICU, uconv doesn't show all encodings

Tags: linux, encoding, icu, icu4c

I built and installed icu-69.1. The ICU data I built into shared libraries, with option --with-data-packaging=library. My goal is that windows-1252 encoding included in ICU data file .

The desired encodding is listed in icu4c/source/data/mappings/convrtrs.txt:

```
ibm-5348_P100-1997 { UTR22* }   ibm-5348 { IBM* } windows-1252 { IANA* JAVA* WINDOWS* } cp1252 { JAVA }         # Windows Latin1 (w/ euro update)
```

On the target mashine it looks good:

```
#ll /usr/share/icu/69.1
-rw-r--r--    1 root      root        28664528 Jan  1  1970 icudt69l.dat
```

I also set the environment variable ICU_DATA to the directory containing the data file:

export ICU_DATA='/usr/share/icu/69.1'

And then I check with the uconv utility, if the win-1252 installed and unfortunately  it was not displayed in list all available encodings.

Did I miss something in the configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: The Solution was easy:
to unlock all converters, the UCONFIG_NO_LEGACY_CONVERSION option should be set to 0.